# Is there a way to proxy GCP HTTPS Load Balancer certificate requests to a backend?

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I have a scenario where I need to manage an increasingly large number of ssl certificates for domains each pointing to the same pair of backends, one kubernetes and one cloud storage bucket. Way more than 15 certificates which is the current maximum per GCP load balancer.

Currently all of the certificates are managed by cert-manager in kubernetes with the TCP load balancer, but now some requests need to be sent to cloud storage directly from the load balancer or a CDN.

Since I have all of the certificates easily available in the kubernetes backend I'd like to just have the https load balancer use them directly. Is anything along those lines possible?

Alternatively, is there a non-google CDN+Cloud Storage provider where something like this is easier (i.e. no 15 cert limit)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to proxy GCP HTTPS Load Balancer certificate requests to a backend because the external connection from load balancer to client terminates at the load balancer and the load balancer creates new connection from itself to the backend.

Also, it is not possible for https load balancer to use the certificates of kubernetes backend, as https load balancer use its own ssl certificates as per GCP norms.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates